# javafx capture textfield changes whenever the user type a character

Tags: javafx-8, textfield

I'm fighting with a javafx textfield and i don't find how to call getText
everytime the text is changed. i'm doing a search box, so i want whenever the user type a character in the textfield i will be able to put it in a string then search for the item in a treeItem .
 I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
m_SearchTextField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>()  {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                        String oldValue, String newValue) {
        String value = m_SearchTextField.getText();
    }
});
```

however I find an answer in google that says we could use this

```
InputMethodListener
    public void caretPositionChanged(InputMethodEvent ev){}
    public void inputMethodTextChanged(InputMethodEvent ev){}
```

but i don't know how to use it really .. :(
or this : scene builder : on input method text changed

anyone knows how to use this functions ? I'll be grateful. thank you

Comment: Your approach of adding a listener to the `textProperty` is correct (but note that the value you get in the handler by calling `getText()` is already present in `newValue`). What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: listening to the textProperty should work - most probably there's some problem in your setup. Please show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you are doing and what went wrong

Comment: @James_D i put the code in the initialize() , then i put a breakpoin  there , when i debug the listner isn't called ... so no event is fired ..

Comment: Then as @kleopatra says, the problem lies elsewhere in your code: to get help you need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (aka SSCCE on other forums ;)).

Comment: the code works i only added a listner and the listner doesn't work ...

Comment: can i post my code ?

Comment: Then it doesn't work, by definition. Edit your question with an MCVE, or no-one will be able to help you. Your MCVE should be enough to reproduce the problem, but the minimal amount to do so (this usually means it should not be your entire application, just one you create specifically to demonstrate the problem).

Comment: and whats SSCCE !__! ?

Comment: SSCCE = [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: MCVE .. why i feel lost .. what is this ?

Comment: did you follow the link?

Comment: haha i feel dumb .. ok what is MCVE

Comment: @James_D finally I found my error (i added something in the fxml and forget to erase it) the listener now works .. hahaha so happy,  thank you guys.

Comment: OK< glad you found the error. In future, please consider positing an MCVE from the outset. More often than not, creating one will lead you to the error anyway.

Comment: ok no problem , I'm new in this site that's why I didn't really noticed that. thanx again for all the answers.